# Filter ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am very new to coding and am trying to learn to code for Windows phone. I am stuck at a problem since the last week and it is driving me crazy.

I have an `ObservableCollection` defined like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Note> Items { get; private set; }
```

The `Note` class has two variables in it called `Index` and `Category`.

I want to filter the `ObservableCollection` so that I can choose a particular element from it.

Is there a simple way doing this? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: BTW, they are not "variables" (variables a local to a method), they are either Properties or Field most likely Properties.

Answer (score 8):

you can do:

```
var myCollection = GetNoteCollection(...);

var result = myCollection.Where(w => w.Category.Equals("MyCategory"));
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: These classes are no longer available, check out [ObservableCollectionView](https://github.com/RicoSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/ObservableCollectionView)

**Original Answer**
Try one of these classes: [`OrderedObservableCollection`](https://github.com/RicoSuter/MyToolkit/blob/master/src/MyToolkit/Collections/OrderedObservableCollection.cs) or [`FilteredObservableCollection`](https://github.com/RicoSuter/MyToolkit/blob/master/src/MyToolkit/Collections/FilteredObservableCollection.cs)

```
OriginalList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
FilteredList = new OrderedObservableCollection<Person, int>(originalList, p => p.Age, a => a.Age >= 18);
```

The `FilteredList` contains only persons with an age >= 18 and all persons are sorted by age. The `FilteredList` will automatically be updated if something changes in `OriginalList`. If `OriginalList` is global and `FilteredList` is used on a page, you have to call `FilteredList.Unload()` to remove the event binding - this is needed that the garbage collector can free the `FilteredList`.

These classes are not fully tested, if you find a problem, please report it here.

BTW: I'm not happy with the `Unload()` method. Is it possible to add something like a weak event reference?

Comment: You might want to update that link to your GitHub page now that CodePlex is shutting down. Also, my first impression was that you were pointing out existing .NET classes, but these are from your own toolkit you've published (I'm assuming, based on the GitHub account name). You may want to mention that in your answer, as well, for full disclosure.

Answer (score 2):

You're not saying what you want to filter it on. But regardless, look at LINQs [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) and [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx)

Example:

```
var answerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything = Items.FirstOrDefault(note => note.Index == 42)
```

Comment: but..I keep getting an error that both "FirstOrDefault" and "Where" are not defined. By the way can I include two search parameters like index==1 && category==2 ??

Comment: You need to include System.Linq in your using statements of course. And yes, you can have as many search-parameters (boolean statements) as you like.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking to use is a CollectViewSource. These are supported in Windows Phone 7.1.
You can create it, wrap your ObservableCollection and set it as a bindable property in the ViewModel.
I am about to try it myself. If you want to know how I get on let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **ListCollectionView** and **List<>** with your **ObservableCollection** property:

1-Binding ListCollectionView to the same data source as **ObservableCollection** as:

```
ListCollectionView lvs;
var note = from n in Note select n;
        lvs = new ListCollectionView(note.ToList <Note>());
```

2- create filter method:

```
public bool ItemIndexFilter(object obj)
    {
        Note note = obj as Note;
        return (note.Index>=10);
    }
```

3- Giving the Items property its filtered value:

```
lvs.Filter = new Predicate<object>(ItemIndexFilter);
List<Note> note_list = new List<Note>();
for (int i = 0; i < lvs.Count; i++)
     {                   
        note_list.Add((Note)lvs.GetItemAt(i));    
     }
var observe = new ObservableCollection<Note>(note_list);
items=observe;
```